# How to insert elements into multiple positions in a vector without iteration

Tags: r

Given a vector `u` of elements and a vector `i` of indices into vector `x`, how can we insert the elements of `u` into `x` after the elements corresponding to the indices in `i`, without iteration?

For example

```
x <- c('a','b','c','d','e')
u <- c('X','X')
i <- c(2,3)
# now we want to get c('a','b','X','c','X','d','e')
```

I want to do this in one step (i.e. avoid loops) because each step requires the creation of a new vector, and in practice these are long vectors.

I'm hoping for some index magic.

Comment: Try `x[i] <- u` Oops...misunderstood the output

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this should work as long as `i` does not contain duplicate indices.

```
idx <- sort(c(seq_along(x), i))
y <- x[idx]
y[duplicated(idx)] <- u
y
#[1] "a" "b" "X" "c" "X" "d" "e"
```

*Edit* 
As @MartinMorgan suggested in the comments, a much better way of doing this is 
`c(x, u)[order(c(seq_along(x), i))]`.

Comment: Or along the same lines `c(x, u)[order(c(seq_along(x), i))]` which maybe handles duplicate and out-of-order `i`?

Comment: @MartinMorgan good one, your way is much better. Maybe post it as an answer which should be the one to get accepted

Comment: I wouldn't have come up with my refinement without your original idea, so the credit is yours @konvas.

Answer (score 1):

In the mean time, I've come up with something that does the job (provided indices in `i` are unique):

```
xn <- rep(NA,length(x))
xn[i] <- u
y <- c(rbind(x,xn))
y <- y[!is.na(y)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my function

```
# vec->source vector, val->values to insert, at->positions to insert

func_insert_vector_at <- function(vec, val, at){
    out=numeric(length(vec)+length(val))
    out[at]=NA
    out[!is.na(out)]=vec
    out[at]=val
    return(out)
}
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: I think the function is concise and self-explanatory. The function does exactly what the question is meant for.